# Using Presentation Model with complex custom controls (which have their own models)

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, architecture, presentation, presentation-model

I have an application which uses [Martin Fowler's Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) with WinForms (WPF would be a better choice, but that's irrelevant).  As such, every view has a presentation model representing it where the UI logic and domain model translation logic reside.  This works very well when the controls in my views are built-in .NET WinForms controls or third-party controls.

In subscribing to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principal, I have a class library used by my application which provides a set of my own custom controls that are used in multiple views in my application; each of these controls is a composite of smaller controls that have some functional relationship.  The custom controls also have their own presentation models that control their UI logic.

My question is, **how can I architect my application so that the concerns of the view are not tied in with the underlying UI logic of my custom controls?**  Here is a diagram:

[image]

I don't want the flow of information from the form's presentation model to the control's presentation model to have to go through the views themselves; but at the same time, the presentation models don't know (nor should they know) about one another.

Comment: I assume myFormPM accesses the built-in controls on MyForm, e.g. MyForm.FieldA. Why don't you want myFormPM to access your custom control in the same way? e.g. MyForm.MyControl

Comment: @MikeStockdale -- It can, for some things.  But imagine that MyControl.Field1 is read-only because it's value is determined by UI logic that is inside MyControlPM.  Now assume that this logic depends on a dynamic factor that is provided by the application when the control is used in the application.  Concrete example:  maybe MyControl.Field1 displays a color -- red, blue, or yellow -- if the consuming application wants it to display colors.  Or, it could display a mood -- happy, sad, angry -- if the consuming application wants it to do that.

Comment: Which "type" is displayed is determined by the application that is using the control.  However, the value of the "type" -- i.e. "red" or "happy" -- is determined by the control's presentation model (MyControlPM).

Comment: OK, I think I understand. MyControl could expose a property DisplayMode that MyFormPM could set: MyForm.MyControl.DisplayMode = Color or MyForm.MyControl.DisplayMode = Mood.  Then MyControlPM can control the display of MyControl.Field1.